# jquery hide toggle when click anywhere on document

Tags: jquery

i'm able to hide dropdown toggle when clicking anywhere on document by using even.stopPropagation() but how do i make it so even when i click on links on the document nothing happens except hiding the toggle dropdown. so basically i don't want anything to happen until i hide the dropdown toggle first.

https://jsfiddle.net/dbgwktxz/

notice when click on menu, the list toggles. when click outside of the div link the list hides. when i click inside the div link the list hides and takes me to google.com. how do i make it so when click inside div link, it hides the list without taking me to google.com. once the list is hidden i can go ahead and click the link if i want to. Thank you for your help.

```
//HTML
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
<div id="dropdown">
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<a href="www.google.com"><div id="link">Google</div></a>

//CSS
#dropdown{
 display: none;
}
#link {
 height: 100px;
 border:1px solid blue;
}

//JQUERY
$("#menu").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("#dropdown").toggle()
});

$(document).click(function(){
  $("#dropdown").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to identify that the click on the document is from your ul's children or not. If the clicked target is not a children or self the ul dont close it.

Use `.closest()` https://api.jquery.com/closest/ Snippet added

```js
//JQUERY
$("#menu").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $("#dropdown").toggle()
});

$(document).click(function(e){
  if($(e.target).closest("#dropdown").length===0){
   $("#dropdown").hide();
  };
});
```

```css
#dropdown{
    border:1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
<div id="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*how do i make it so when click inside div link, it hides the list without taking me to google.com.**once the list is hidden i can go ahead and click the link if i want to**.*

change your selector to:

```
$("#menu, #link")
```

and make use of `event.preventDefault();`.

---

Like below:

```
//JQUERY
$("#menu, #link").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  if(event.target.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a" && 
      $("#dropdown").is(':visible')){ 
      event.preventDefault();
  }
  $("#dropdown").toggle()
});
```

#### [Your updated fiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/dbgwktxz/2/)